# Loading STL file to STL viewer

Tags: php, ce-1.9.0.1

I set up a sample store, uploaded 3 products, then uploaded 1 STL file for each product. They were stored in database successfully.
In `files` table, it is like this.
[image: files]

And in catalog_product_entity_varchar table, the `attribute_id` is `71` for all 3 products.
So when I click on `Click Here To View Associated STL file in STL viewer` link as shown in below screen shot, then STL image from `files` table should load into STL viewer which is in another web page.
[image: addfile]
How to access the STL file from `files` table?
This code is incomplete, help me to complete it.

```
$resource=Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$readConnection=$resource->getConnection('core/resource');
$table=$resource->getTableName('files');
$query="select * from '. $table .' where file_id/prod_id ='value'";
$result=$resource->fetchcol($query);
```

Comment: @marius: Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

```
        $resource=Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $readConnection=$resource->getConnection('core/resource');
        $table=$resource->getTableName('files');
        $query="select * from '. $table .' where prod_id = ". $product_id;
        $result=$resource->fetchAll($query);
```

please check the query, you should use the product id to get the related data. Moreover, to get all the related data, you should use `fetchAll` if multiple data is possible OR `fetchRow` in case one product will have single entry only. `$result` will have everything related to that specific product Id as an array and you can use the data for your purposes.

Comment: That is correct code :) But how to load that STL file from magento to STL viewer which is in another web page?

Comment: do you know how your STL viewer takes the file?

Comment: Yes. Currently it is taking files from local system. But I want to load STL file from magento to STL viewer.

Comment: What does $product_id mean?

Comment: does that STL viewer has any feature to load the files other than local system?

Comment: $product_id will be the reference to the `prod_id`, the column in your database, if its your Magento product id

Comment: No... It doesn't have that feature

Comment: can you provide the link of that stl viewer

Comment: It isn't yet online.... It is in my development server. But this is another version of STL viewer which my team mate built. Its behavior is similar to my STL viewer. http://proto3000.dfthreed.com/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15739/discussion-between-ajay-kulkarni-and-mtm).